# Error while parsing JSON from analytics

Tags: java, json, parsing, exception, google-analytics

I need help with below.

I have json data from Google analytics in below form :

```
{"visitNumber":"3","fullVisitorId":"33283173096445"}
{"visitNumber":"2","fullVisitorId":"58516104158964"}
...............(upto 100k records)
```

and java code I have is :

```
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonElement root = parser.parse(jsonData);
```

based on GSON libraries. I am getting "MalformedJsonException" while running this.

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected EOF at line 1 column 53
```

Comment: I'm not sure the error could've been much clearer here. That is malformed JSON (as a single document). As "up to 100k" separate JSON documents, its fine, but together it is malformed.

Comment: Each and every record should be separated by , (comma). That's said, if you do:
[{"visitNumber":"3","fullVisitorId":"33283173096445"},
{"visitNumber":"2","fullVisitorId":"58516104158964"}]

It will become a valid JSON

Comment: @ssc I formatted the way you suggested. But I am getting this response from google analytics, around 100K records, it would be impossible to insert [,] in all of them. How to fix it programmatically before parsing it..?

Comment: @nix_stack You just need to append [ in the very start and ] in the very end. But you need to append , (comma) after every {"visitNumber":"3","fullVisitorId":"33283173096445"} to make it valid json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried below and it works.

```
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        String line = br.readLine();
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        JsonObject root = (JsonObject)parser.parse(line);;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse each line, and add it to an array manually. Either [split the line](//stackoverflow.com/questions/454908/split-java-string-by-new-line) using `String.split()` (Shown below), or read through your file line by line, and add them to the array manually.

```
var data = jsonData.split("\\r?\\n");
var finalData = [];

for ( var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++ )
{
    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();

    JsonElement root = parser.parse(data[i]);
    finalData.push(root);
}

console.log(finalData);
```